# Problema Cuatro en linea

Tags: java

buenos días tengo un problema con un trabajo que estoy haciendo en java de cuatro en linea.

Primero tengo dos jugadores, el `jugador 1` que es `'x'` y el `jugador 2` que es `'o'` y me gustaría hacer que cuando pongo una fila por ejemplo 1 se me pusiera la ficha del jugador en la fila 1 y lo mismo si presiono 2 o cualquier otro numero de la fila.

Es un tablero elegido por el usuario así que no puedo poner-lo estático tendría que ir cambiando.

Comment: y las columnas como quedarían? cuál es la diferencia del tres en línea y el cuatro en línea? Esperas que te respondamos con texto o que incluyamos código? ( porque yo no vi que incluyeras tu código )

Comment: no entendí lo último puedes editar tu pregunta y agregarlo allí?

Comment: el tablero solo es hecho con los simbolos del teclado?

Comment: Si esta echo solo con simbolos del teclado